# Retrieving component class from object in C#

Tags: c#

I have a base abstract class `Component` and a class `GameObject` with a list of Components. I want to retrieve a component from that list but I can't figure out how.

```cs
public T GetComponent<T>() {
    foreach (Component Component in Components) // Components is a list
       if (Component is T)
           return (T)(object)Component;

    return (T)(object)null;
}
```

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: Can you provide us with more details? `GetComponent` is your code? It resides in class `GameObject`? The code I read simply means "return the component with the class of type T"

Comment: GetComponent is a method inside of class GameObject. The current code seems to not be working, as I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error when I call it

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified using Linq to this line:

```
public T GetComponent<T>()
{
    return this.Components.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

If that throws a `NullReferenceException`, then `Components` is `null` and you need to initialize it.

Comment: It still throws a `NullReferenceException`, but `Components` is not null. The function stopped working since I started using Json.NET to save and load a `Scene` class which has all the GameObjects stored within

Comment: I guess you will need to use a debugger to solve that problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it